# How to choose which is the reference in Data::Dumper

Tags: perl, hash

Let's consider this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $node = node(undef, undef, 'root');
my $root = $node;

$node = node($root, $node, 'tom');
push $root->{children}, $node; 

$node = node($root, $node, 'clarence');
push $root->{children}, $node;

Data::Dumper::Purity;
#$root->{children}[0]->{younger} = $root->{children}[1];

print Dumper $root;

sub node {
    return {
        parent => shift,
        prev   => shift,
        name   => shift,
        children => [],
    };
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'parent' => undef,
          'prev' => undef,
          'name' => 'root',
          'children' => [
                          {
                            'parent' => $VAR1,
                            'prev' => $VAR1,
                            'name' => 'tom',
                            'children' => []
                          },
                          {
                            'parent' => $VAR1,
                            'prev' => $VAR1->{'children'}[0],
                            'name' => 'clarence',
                            'children' => []
                          }
                        ]
        };
```

We can clearly see that `root` has 2 children named `tom` and `clarence`. The reference of `clarence` on `tom` is really clear `$VAR1->{'children'}[0]`.

However, if I add a reference on `tom` to `clarence` with `$root->{children}[0]->{younger} = $root->{children}[1];`, the output get messed up:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'parent' => undef,
          'prev' => undef,
          'name' => 'root',
          'children' => [
                          {
                            'parent' => $VAR1,
                            'prev' => $VAR1,
                            'younger' => {
                                           'parent' => $VAR1,
                                           'prev' => $VAR1->{'children'}[0],
                                           'name' => 'clarence',
                                           'children' => []
                                         },
                            'name' => 'tom',
                            'children' => []
                          },
                          $VAR1->{'children'}[0]{'younger'}
                        ]
        };
```

Is there any possibility to constraint `Data::Dumper` or any other dumper to always consider some keys as references in order to properly display a tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a lot you can do because `Data::Dumper` scans structures depth-first, but I suggest that you use

```
$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1
```

which will duplicate hash values in the output instead of inserting cross-references. This is the result

```
$VAR1 = {
          'prev' => undef,
          'children' => [
                          {
                            'parent' => $VAR1,
                            'name' => 'tom',
                            'younger' => {
                                           'children' => [],
                                           'prev' => $VAR1->{'children'}[0],
                                           'name' => 'clarence',
                                           'parent' => $VAR1
                                         },
                            'prev' => $VAR1,
                            'children' => []
                          },
                          {
                            'children' => [],
                            'prev' => {
                                        'parent' => $VAR1,
                                        'name' => 'tom',
                                        'younger' => $VAR1->{'children'}[1],
                                        'prev' => $VAR1,
                                        'children' => []
                                      },
                            'name' => 'clarence',
                            'parent' => $VAR1
                          }
                        ],
          'parent' => undef,
          'name' => 'root'
        };
```